# How to calculate max requests per second of a Django app?

Tags: python, django, deployment, concurrency, python-requests

I am about the deploy a Django app, and then it struck me that I couldn't find a way to anticipate how many requests per second my application can handle.

Is there a way of calculating how many requests per second can a Django application handle, without resorting to things like doing a test deployment and use an external tool such as [locust](https://locust.io/)?

I know there are several factors involved (such as number of database queries, etc.), but perhaps there is a convenient way of calculating, even estimating, how many visitors can a single Django app instance handle.

**EDIT**: Removed the mention to Gunicorn, since it only adds confusion to what I truly wanted to know.

Comment: Calculating anything like max throughput is bound to be really tricky, your best bet is to run a load test and *measure* the max throughput empirically.

Comment: @mackorone so far, this seems like the only option, but maybe there is someone in the community who can come up with a clever solution ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of calculating how many requests per second can a
>   Django application handle, without resorting to things like doing a
>   test deployment and use an external tool such as locust?

No and Yes.  As mackarone pointed out, I don't think there's anyway you avoid measuring it.  Consider the case where you did a local benchmark on your local dev server talking to a local DB instance, in order to generate a baseline for estimation.  The issue with this is that the hardware, network (distance between services) all make a huge difference.  So any numbers you generated locally would be relatively worthless for capacity planning.

In my experiences, local testing is great for *relative* changes.   Consider the case where you wanted to see the performance impact of sql query planninng.  Establishing a local baseline, making the change, than observing the effect locally *is* useful to gauge relative speedup.

**How to generate these numbers?**

I would recommend deploying the app to the hardware, and network you plan on testing on.  This deploy should use your production configuration and component topology (ie if you're going to run gunicorn, make sure gunicorn is running instead of NGINX, or if you're going to have a proxy in front of gunicorn, make sure that is setup.  I would run a single instance of your application using your production config.

Once this is running, I would launch a load test against the single instance using any of the popular load testing tools:

- [Apache Benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
- [Siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege)
- [Vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta)
- [K6](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6)
- etc

You can launch these load tests from your single machine and ramp up traffic until response times are no longer acceptable in order to get a feel for the # of concurrent connections, and throughput your application can accommodate.

Now you have some idea of what a single instance of your service is able to handle.  Up until your db (or other shared resources) are saturated these numbers can be used to project how many instances of your service are necessary to handle some amount of traffic!

Comment: Thanks! 
It seems like a fairly complex topic, and googling around, I couldn't find any resources discussing their results, at least to have an idea of how well the average Django app is performing in the wild...

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html) documentation

> How Many Workers?
>
> **DO NOT scale the number of workers to the number of clients you expect to have**. Gunicorn should only need **4-12 worker processes to handle hundreds or thousands of requests per second**.
>
> Gunicorn relies on the operating system to provide all of the load balancing when handling requests. **Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1** as the number of workers to start off with. While not overly scientific, the formula is based on the assumption that for a given core, one worker will be reading or writing from the socket while the other worker is processing a request.
>
> Obviously, your particular hardware and application are going to affect the optimal number of workers. Our recommendation is to **start with the above guess and tune using TTIN and TTOU signals while the application is under load**.
>
> Always remember, **there is such a thing as too many workers**. After a point your worker processes will start thrashing system resources decreasing the throughput of the entire system.

The best thing is tune it using some load testing tool as locust as you mentioned.

Emphasis mine

Comment: Perhaps I made the mistake of including Gunicorn in my description. Even if one Gunicorn worker is very efficient, it boils down to how quickly your Django app is able to answer to a request. I want to be able to know how many requests my Django application is able to handle per unit of time...

Answer (score 1):

You have to install (loadtest) first, it is a npm package,
I was learning redis and at that time I found this, you can use it, it worked for me,
For More check this tutorial: https://realpython.com/caching-in-django-with-redis/#start-by-measuring-performance

```
npm install -g loadtest

loadtest -n 100 -k  http://localhost:8000/myUrl/
```